# Scroll bar in individual column

Tags: html, css, angularjs

In body overflow is scroll and in a page two column are there I want to that first column is fixed and another is scroll and it is also important that overflow on the body is scroll we do not remove that

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-7 fixed">
     </div>
   <div class="col-5 scroll ">
     </div>     
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set the overflow on scroll class to scroll.

```
  .scroll {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: but on screen, there are two scrolls are visible

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? and also more code if possible?

Comment: If you have scrolling enabled on body and on the container you will have two scrollbars. No way around that.

Comment: @cloned but we can hide scrollbar

Comment: Basically, in col-7 there is an iframe and I want to that fixed, in col-5 there is something like a form  and I want  only to scroll form after form I will redirect to result  page in which I also want to show scroll that's why I apply scroll on the body and it is important

Comment: Then you don't have scrolling enabled on the body tag. If you have scrolling enabled (as stated in question) you will end up with two scrollbars.

Comment: @avi Do you have a height set to col-5 that you want to match to col-7? I think I finally get what's going on.  You might need to set a height to col-5 so it will scroll. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/gjuh4nqy/1/

Answer (score 1):

Is this something you want?

I have given fixed height to both containers. Given `overflow: auto` to `scroll` div. And hide scrollbar, so that there will be only one scrollbar of body on the page.

```css
.col-7 {
  float: left;
  width: 58.33%;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.4);
  height: 150px;
}

.col-5 {
  float: left;
  width: 41.67%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.4);
  height: 150px;
}

.row {}

.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
}

.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-7 fixed">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div class="col-5 scroll ">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @avi you should select this as the best answer then.  It helps future people find the best answer quickly and gives Kenny a little rep boost for giving the best answer.